# How can i get this Jquery slide to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get my jQuery slide to work?

https://codepen.io/kasiraket/pen/KmKYmL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-icon').click(function() {
        $(".search-container").slideToggle("400", function(){
            $(".search-container input").toggleClass("show");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `slideToggle()` and `toggleClass()` are firing opposite eachother. When your container is shown, the inputs are hidden - and when the inputs are shown, the container is hidden.

Just add a `display: none;` to the `search-container` initially, so that both the container and inputs are in the same state.

```
.search-container {
   display: none;
   /*...the rest of your CSS*/
}
```

**Here is your fixed example:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjbwPo

---

**EDIT:**  Please review [Daniel H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401385/2026606) - he makes a good point. Simply *adding* the `display: none;` will cause issues with the first click. Consider instead *moving* the `display: none;` from `search-container input` to `search-container`.

---

You may be wondering what I mean, considering the container is clearly not on the page when it loads; it's important to realize that the only reason it isn't showing is because all of its contents (the inputs) are hidden. If you right click on the page and go to Inspect Element, you can very clearly see that when you click the search icon, `display: none;` is getting added to `search-container` at the same time `show` is getting added to the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move `display: none;` from  `search-container input` to `search-container`, no need to hide the child element, just hide the container.

**codepen:**
https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/EmaKeL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search-icon').click(function() {
    $(".search-container").slideToggle("400");
  });
});
```

Comment: @Santi I will upvote yours, but your solution will miss the 1st click. you need to move display: none; from  search-container input to search-container.

Comment: You are correct, I apologize. I've removed my comment.